# Write a file in UTF-8 using FileWriter (Java)?

Tags: java, file-io, unicode, utf-8, file-format

I have the following code however, I want it to write as a UTF-8 file to handle foreign characters.  Is there a way of doing this, is there some need to have a parameter?

I would really appreciate your help with this.  Thanks.

```
try {
  BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:/Users/Jess/My Documents/actresses.list"));
  writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("C:/Users/Jess/My Documents/actressesFormatted.csv"));
  while( (line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    //If the line starts with a tab then we just want to add a movie
    //using the current actor's name.
    if(line.length() == 0)
      continue;
    else if(line.charAt(0) == '\t') {
      readMovieLine2(0, line, surname.toString(), forename.toString());
    } //Else we've reached a new actor
    else {
      readActorName(line);
    }
  }
} catch (IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 86):

## Safe Encoding Constructors

Getting Java to properly notify you of encoding errors is tricky. You must use the **most verbose** and, alas, the ***least used*** of the four alternate contructors for each of `InputStreamReader` and `OutputStreamWriter` to receive a proper exception on an encoding glitch.

For file I/O, always make sure to always use as the second argument to both `OutputStreamWriter` and `InputStreamReader` the fancy encoder argument:

```
  Charset.forName("UTF-8").newEncoder()
```

There are other even fancier possibilities, but none of the three simpler possibilities work for exception handing. These do:

```
 OutputStreamWriter char_output = new OutputStreamWriter(
     new FileOutputStream("some_output.utf8"),
     Charset.forName("UTF-8").newEncoder() 
 );

 InputStreamReader char_input = new InputStreamReader(
     new FileInputStream("some_input.utf8"),
     Charset.forName("UTF-8").newDecoder() 
 );
```

As for running with

```
 $ java -Dfile.encoding=utf8 SomeTrulyRemarkablyLongcLassNameGoeShere
```

The problem is that that will not use the full encoder argument form for the character streams, and so you will again miss encoding problems.

## Longer Example

Here’s a longer example, this one managing a process instead of a file, where we  promote two different input bytes streams and one output byte stream all to UTF-8 character streams *with full exception handling*:

```
 // this runs a perl script with UTF-8 STD{IN,OUT,ERR} streams
 Process
 slave_process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("perl -CS script args");

 // fetch his stdin byte stream...
 OutputStream
 __bytes_into_his_stdin  = slave_process.getOutputStream();

 // and make a character stream with exceptions on encoding errors
 OutputStreamWriter
   chars_into_his_stdin  = new OutputStreamWriter(
                             __bytes_into_his_stdin,
         /* DO NOT OMIT! */  Charset.forName("UTF-8").newEncoder()
                         );

 // fetch his stdout byte stream...
 InputStream
 __bytes_from_his_stdout = slave_process.getInputStream();

 // and make a character stream with exceptions on encoding errors
 InputStreamReader
   chars_from_his_stdout = new InputStreamReader(
                             __bytes_from_his_stdout,
         /* DO NOT OMIT! */  Charset.forName("UTF-8").newDecoder()
                         );

// fetch his stderr byte stream...
 InputStream
 __bytes_from_his_stderr = slave_process.getErrorStream();

 // and make a character stream with exceptions on encoding errors
 InputStreamReader
   chars_from_his_stderr = new InputStreamReader(
                             __bytes_from_his_stderr,
         /* DO NOT OMIT! */  Charset.forName("UTF-8").newDecoder()
                         );
```

Now you have three character streams that all raise exception on encoding errors, respectively called `chars_into_his_stdin`, `chars_from_his_stdout`, and `chars_from_his_stderr`.

This is only slightly more complicated that what you need for your problem, whose solution I gave in the first half of this answer.  The key point is this is the only way to detect encoding errors.

Just don’t get me started about `PrintStream`s eating exceptions.

Comment: Great answer, but I think there is a minor bug with it -`InputStreamReader char_input = new InputStreamWriter` should read: `InputStreamReader char_input = new InputStreamReader `, and the `InputStreamReader` constructor takes a `CharsetDecoder`, not a `CharsetEncoder`.

Comment: But is this a real problem, what is is not possible for UTF-8 to represent, I thought it could encode anything.

Comment: If you want to complain about Streams eating exceptions, try `CipherInputStream`, that removes `BadPaddingException`'s, even if they are created by an authenticated cipher stream :(

Comment: I found a little error in your code:
"Charset.forName("UTF-8").newEncoder()" for "InputStreamReader" should be "Charset.forName("UTF-8").newDecoder()". So "decoder" instead of "encoder". But anyway, thanks for this nice answer and +1. :)

Comment: Does closing the OutputStreamWriter  also close the FileOutputStream?

Comment: (The whole Java IO system has always been a mess.  Should be completely reworked like Joda Time reworked dates.)

Answer (score 67):

Ditch `FileWriter` and `FileReader`, which are useless exactly because they do not allow you to specify the encoding. Instead, use

`new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(file), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)`

and

`new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);`

Comment: If you don’t use the very verbose `Charset.forName("UTF-8").newDecoder()` argument (or some fancier construct) instead of just `"UTF-8"`, you won’t be properly notified of encoding errors (read: exceptions will be suppressed, and it will mysteriously hide encoding errors).

Comment: `new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(file), StandardCharsets.UTF_8 )`

Comment: This is the way to go, it works like a charm...

Answer (score 50):

You need to use the `OutputStreamWriter` class as the writer parameter for your `BufferedWriter`. It does accept an encoding. Review [javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/OutputStreamWriter.html) for it.

Somewhat like this:

```
BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
    new FileOutputStream("jedis.txt"), "UTF-8"
));
```

Or you can set the current system encoding with the system property `file.encoding` to UTF-8.

```
java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 com.jediacademy.Runner arg1 arg2 ...
```

You may also set it as a system property at runtime with `System.setProperty(...)` if you only need it for this specific file, but in a case like this I think I would prefer the `OutputStreamWriter`.

By setting the system property you can use `FileWriter` and expect that it will use UTF-8 as the default encoding for your files. In this case for all the files that you read and write.

**EDIT**

- Starting from API 19, you can replace the String "UTF-8" with `StandardCharsets.UTF_8`
- As suggested in the comments below by [tchrist](https://stackoverflow.com/users/471272/tchrist), if you intend to detect encoding errors in your file you would be forced to use the `OutputStreamWriter` approach and use the constructor that receives a charset encoder.

  Somewhat like

  ```
  CharsetEncoder encoder = Charset.forName("UTF-8").newEncoder();
  encoder.onMalformedInput(CodingErrorAction.REPORT);
  encoder.onUnmappableCharacter(CodingErrorAction.REPORT);
  BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream("jedis.txt"),encoder));
  ```

  You may choose between actions `IGNORE | REPLACE | REPORT`

Also, this question was already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/361975/setting-the-default-java-character-encoding).

Comment: That’s not enough. You also need an `InputStreamReader(InputStream in, CharsetDecoder dec)`, such that the last argument is `Charset.forName("UTF-8").newDecoder()`.

Comment: Input encoding errors will be silently dropped if you do it that.

Comment: There is no need for an encoder. The constructor accepts either a String, a Charset or an Encoder in both the Input/Output classes. Not sure what you mean by your comment. Can you elaborate,please?

Comment: @edalorzo If you test out the four different `{In,Out}putStream{Reader,Writer}` constructers on erroneous data, you’ll discover that three of them **mask all exceptions** that *should* arise from encoding errors, and only the fourth form correctly delivers them to you. That’s the one that involves `Charset.forName("UTF-8").newDecoder()`. I explain this a bit in my answer.

Comment: @tchist I just improved the answer with your comments b(^_^)d

Comment: Yes, that’s much better.  It’s  *much* more often with input encoding errors where this comes up than it comes up with output (at least if it’s a UTF form: 8-bit output encodings are always *lose-lose* in Unicode.) However, you can in theory still incur them on output because Java allows unpaired surrogates to exist in strings in memory (it *has* to; this is not a bug!), but no conformant UTF-{8,16,32} output encoder is allowed to produce them on output.

Answer (score 12):

Since Java 11 you can do:

```
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("filename.txt", Charset.forName("utf-8"));
```

Answer (score 9):

Since Java 7 there is an easy way to handle character encoding of BufferedWriter and BufferedReaders. You can create a BufferedWriter directly by using the Files class instead of creating various instances of Writer. You can simply create a BufferedWriter, which considers character encoding, by calling:

```
Files.newBufferedWriter(file.toPath(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

You can find more about it in JavaDoc:

- [Files class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html)
- [Files#newBufferedWriter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#newBufferedWriter-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.charset.Charset-java.nio.file.OpenOption...-)

Answer (score 6):

With Chinese text, I tried to use the Charset UTF-16 and lucklily it work.

Hope this could help!

```
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter( file, "UTF-16" );
```

Comment: can try with UTF-32

Answer (score 1):

OK it's 2019 now, and from Java 11 you have a constructor with Charset:

```
FileWriter​(String fileName, Charset charset)
```

> Unfortunately, we still cannot modify the byte buffer size, and it's
>   set to 8192. (https://www.baeldung.com/java-filewriter)

Answer (score 1):

use OutputStream instead of FileWriter to set encoding type

```java
// file is your File object where you want to write you data 
OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8");
outputStreamWriter.write(json); // json is your data 
outputStreamWriter.flush();
outputStreamWriter.close();
```

Answer (score -3):

In my opinion

If you wanna write follow kind **UTF-8**.You should create a byte array.Then,you can do such as the following:
`byte[] by=("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>"+"Your string".getBytes();`

Then, you can write each byte into file you created.
Example:

```
OutputStream f=new FileOutputStream(xmlfile);
    byte[] by=("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>"+"Your string".getBytes();
    for (int i=0;i<by.length;i++){
    byte b=by[i];
    f.write(b);

    }
    f.close();
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!