# Generate PDF with chinese characters in android

Tags: android, pdf

I'm trying to generate PDF file on android with some Chinese characters using below code.It is working fine without Chinese characters(Only English) and PDF size is around 40-50Kb.
But when I try to generate PDF with Chinese characters ,it is working and PDF  size is 3-4MB.

Number of characters for both cases are almost same.
Any idea how to reduce the PDF size?
Because i need to upload the PDF to server.

```
public void generatePDFDoc(Activity activity, View view, String pdfFileName){

    {
        File pdfFile = null;
        PrintAttributes printAttrs = new PrintAttributes.Builder().
                setColorMode(PrintAttributes.COLOR_MODE_COLOR).
                setMediaSize(PrintAttributes.MediaSize.NA_LETTER).
                setResolution(new PrintAttributes.Resolution("print", activity.PRINT_SERVICE,
                        25, 25)).
                setMinMargins(PrintAttributes.Margins.NO_MARGINS).
                build();

        PdfDocument document = new PrintedPdfDocument(activity, printAttrs);
        View content = view;
        int width = content.getWidth();
        int height = content.getHeight();
        PdfDocument.PageInfo pageInfo = new PdfDocument.PageInfo.Builder(width, height, 1).create();
        PdfDocument.Page page = document.startPage(pageInfo);
        content.draw(page.getCanvas());
        document.finishPage(page);
        try {
            pdfFile = new File(pdfFileName);
            if (pdfFile != null) {
                FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(pdfFile);
                document.writeTo(os);
                document.close();
                os.close();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Error generating file", e);
        } finally {
            if (pdfFile != null) {
                //Success Generate PDF file

            }
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried with UTF-8 encoding? 
http://stackoverflow.com/a/9853261/5281666

Comment: Thanks.How can we add UTF-8 to FileOutputStream ? Because   document.writeTo(os); expecting FileOutputstream as parameter.

Comment: BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream("jedis.txt"), "UTF-8"));

Comment: Thanks.Issue is here,  document.writeTo(os);..I need FileOutputStream  with UTF encoding. not  Writer.writeTo method accept only OutputStream not writer.

Comment: Actually, i have found the issue, Chinese characters are printing like an  images not like character.This is the reason for increase PDF file size.But still i don't have workaround to fix this.

Comment: I had encountered this issue. Do you have any workaround to fix it now?

Comment: Yes. I have fixed this. You need to use chinese font inside your application.copy chinese font it to raw folder and set all Textview/Editview to that font.I used simsun.ttc