# Reading a .txt file to a map and then save it again as .txt?

Tags: java, text, save

I have some trouble with reading and saving a `.txt` file

The `.txt` file is a Wordlist with words where every word also have a attached number (integer). So its looks like:

```
hello,0
bye,3
maby,0
...
```

I have already a function created to read and load the word with their numbers into the problem is this is not working for special characters which I need because I am from Germany.

Every special character is transferred into a `?` or an empty block. So I need some help to modify my read and save function to be able so save and read `ä`, `ö`, `ü` and `ß` chars.

```
public void loadWordList(Map<String,Integer> map){       
    try{
        File toRead=new File("Wortliste.txt");
        FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream(toRead);  // Ist bereits in einer Try and Catch

        Scanner sc=new Scanner(fis);

        Map<String,String> mapInFile=new HashMap<String,String>();

        //read data from file line by line:
        String currentLine;
        while(sc.hasNextLine()){
            currentLine=sc.nextLine();
            //now tokenize the currentLine:
            StringTokenizer st=new StringTokenizer(currentLine,",",false);
            //put tokens ot currentLine in map
            map.put(st.nextToken(),Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken()));
        }
        fis.close();
    }catch(Exception e){System.out.println("Wortliste konnte nicht gefunden werden");}  // Ist bereits in einer Try and Catch
}
    //******************************************************************************
    //Speichern der Wordliste für Wortvorschläge           
    //******************************************************************************
public void saveWordList(Map<String,Integer> map){
    try{
    File fileTwo=new File("Wortliste.txt");
    FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream(fileTwo);   // Ist bereits in einer Try and Catch
        PrintWriter pw=new PrintWriter(fos);

        for(Map.Entry<String,Integer> m :map.entrySet()){  // Andere schreibweise
            pw.println(m.getKey()+","+m.getValue());
        }
        System.out.println("Word gespeichert");
        pw.flush();
        pw.close();
        fos.close();
    }catch(Exception e){System.out.println("Wortliste konnte nicht gespeichert werden");}   // Ist bereits in einer Try and Catch
}
```

Comment: I always thought java used Unicode strings - which should deal automatically with these chars...

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9852978/write-a-file-in-utf-8-using-filewriter-java

Answer (score 0):

Try reading the file as below:

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
       new InputStreamReader(
                  new FileInputStream(file), "UTF8"));
```

Comment: still the same thing cant read the special chars and when i use UTF-16 he wount read anything

Comment: Maybe you could upload a sample file?

Comment: what do you mean with sample file? i manegd to get it to work to read the special  chars with using:         Charset inputCharset = Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1");
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fis, inputCharset); But with that i have the problem that he just reads 104 lines from the .txt file and not all 424