# How to force content from a file to be utf-8 in java spring?

Tags: java, spring, file, utf-8, utf

I have a function that creates a file, but when I check the created file, its contents are not in utf-8, which causes problems with the contents in latin languages.

I thought that indicating the media type as html would be enough to keep formatting, but it did not work.

```
File file = new File("name of file");
        try (OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(file), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)) {
            writer.write(contents);
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();

            MultipartFile multipartFileToSend = new MockMultipartFile("file", "name of file", MediaType.TEXT_HTML_VALUE, Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(file.getPath())));

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I'd like to know how to force this, because so far I have not figured out how.

Any tips?

Comment: nop, I'm not using BufferedReader reader

Comment: How do you verify that the contents is not in utf-8, and if it is not utf-8, what is it? Because your code as shown will write UTF-8 to `file`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Write a file in UTF-8 using FileWriter (Java)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9852978/write-a-file-in-utf-8-using-filewriter-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `FileWriter`, create a `FileOutputStream`. You can then wrap this in an `OutputStreamWriter`, which allows you to pass an encoding in the constructor. Then you can write your data to that inside a [try-with-resources Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html):

```
try (OutputStreamWriter writer =
             new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream("your_file_name"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: what is this PROPERTIES_FILE?

Comment: It is basically whatever name you want to give to the file you are writing/creating..

Comment: Well I change to your example but it not work, the file content is ANSI.

Comment: Did you use "StandardCharsets.UTF_8" argument?