# Save CSV file with encoding UTF-8 with Java

Tags: java, csv, export-to-csv

I'm trying to create a CSV file with java contains some data in Arabic letters but when I open the file I found Arabic letters appears as symbols.
here is my code :

```
String csvFilePath = "test.csv";
BufferedWriter fileWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(csvFilePath));
fileWriter.write("الاسم ، السن ، العنوان");
```

and data in CSV file appears like that

```
ط´ط±ظٹط·
```

so How can I solve this issue ?

Comment: If you rename the file from .csv to .txt does it then show correctly? Besides UTF-8 there is also the Right-To-Left control and CSV is also column based.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in [Write a file in UTF-8 using FileWriter (Java)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9852978/write-a-file-in-utf-8-using-filewriter-java) you should use `OutputStreamWriter` and `FileOutputStream` instead of `FileWriter` and specify the encoding:

```java
String csvFilePath = "test.csv";
FileOutputStream file = new FileOutputStream(csvFilePath);
OutputStreamWriter fileWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(file, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
fileWriter.write("الاسم ، السن ، العنوان");
fileWriter.close();
```

---

**Edit after comment:**

To make sure the source code's encoding is not the problem, escape your unicode string like this:

```java
fileWriter.write("\u0627\u0644\u0627\u0633\u0645\u0020\u060c\u0020\u0627\u0644\u0633\u0646\u0020\u060c\u0020\u0627\u0644\u0639\u0646\u0648\u0627\u0646");
```

Comment: Even better: use try-with-resources. This makes sure it's always closed, no matter any exceptions occurring while opening and using the fileWiter.

Comment: Maybe your source code is wrongly encoded? How is your editor or your IDE set?

Comment: I tried to write the same code but print data into txt file and Arabic letters appears normal but this issue happened in csv

Comment: What program did you use to open the csv file?

Comment: Microsoft excel 365

Comment: Maybe that's the problem. Try it with your browser or a simple text editor.

Comment: I tried to open it with notepad and Arabic letters appears normal

Comment: That means the problem is solved? Was it just the program that opened the csv file or the code too?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the file is defined as follows.

`String file = fileName+"."+fileExtension;`

The variable fileName is locale-dependent, i.e in Arabic it contains "تصدير" and in English "export". The variable fileExtension always contains "csv".

Now, the problem is that the variable file looks like "csv.تصدير" in Arabic and "export.csv" in English.

Is this the correct way for a file in Arabic or should it look like "تصدير.csv"?

Comment: Ask this as a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned: use an OutputStreamWriter. Additionally you can write “\uFEFF” as a first character. This will act as a byte order mark and it helps applications like excel to know which encoding you used.

Answer (score 0):

When Microsoft Excel saves files at CSV UTF-8 it adds three bytes to the beginning of the file. Here is a java function to accomplish this purpose:

```
  public static void makeFileExcelUTF8(String filename) {
    try {
      Path path = Paths.get(filename);
      byte[] fileBytes = Files.readAllBytes(path);
      if (fileBytes[0] == (byte) 239 && fileBytes[1] == (byte) 187 && fileBytes[2] == (byte) 191) {
        System.out.println(filename + " is already in excel utf8 format");
        return;
      }
      byte[] prefixBytes = new byte[3];
      prefixBytes[0] = (byte) 239;
      prefixBytes[1] = (byte) 187;
      prefixBytes[2] = (byte) 191;
      Files.write(path, prefixBytes);
      Files.write(path, fileBytes, StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
      System.out.println("problem saving into excel utf8 format");
    }
  }
```